# How to use shortcodes on multiple custom template pages

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Still learning wordpress and trying to navigate my way around adding a different shortcode to pages that use the same custom template.

Using this shortcode example I can place it in the template file in the spot I need it:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');?>
```

The issue is I need to produce multiple pages each with its own unique shortcode. My "obstacles" are;

- cannot use shortcode in text editor because it does not recognise template content
- cannot add using Elementor because the template area is fixed
- how can I specify what part of the page to show the shortcode

I believe there a is way using do_shortcode with a filter hook in the functions.php file of the child theme something like this;

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):
  while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    if ( get_the_content() !== '' ):
      echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() );
    endif; 
  endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

I am a beginner and not sure which way to do it and hoping to learn from the experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Gutenberg, I was able to insert the slider in the content area. I could then reference the content area in the custom template in the spot I wanted it to using this code:

```
<?php echo the_content("slider");?>
```

Thank you @Chris Maverick and @AshOur for your input which helped me on this learning path.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current post, post_id inside the shortcode, then proceed based on it's custom meta, etc..

Inside the shortcode function.

```
global $post;

$post_id = $post->ID;
$custom_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-key', true );
...
```